# How can I fill kendo panelbar by datatable from controller in MVC c#

Tags: kendo-ui, panelbar

I not found any demo in kendo UI for binding with remote source!

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI Panelbar doesn't support binding to remote data sources. This is the reason you haven't found any demos.